# Table join confusion retrieving data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from a relational table to show information from the ids fed into it.

I have 3 tables:

```
users
id
username
email
password

projects
id
name

fave_project
id
user_id
project_id
```

I want to query the relational table to show the name of the projects which are associated a particular users id which I am storing in a variable via sessions.

Here i my SQL query which works to a point but is duplicating the results:

```
$sql = "SELECT fav_project.project_id, fav_project.user_id, project.id, project.name
        FROM fav_project
        JOIN users
        JOIN project
        ON fav_project.project_id = project.id
        WHERE fav_project.user_id = $userId";
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample of my output:

```
array(4) { ["project_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["name"]=> string(12) "Test Project" } array(4) { ["project_id"]=> string(2) "12" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["name"]=> string(15) "Awesome project" } array(4) { ["project_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["name"]=> string(12) "Test Project" } array(4) { ["project_id"]=> string(2) "12" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["name"]=> string(15) "Awesome project" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has more than one project then you will see duplicate user ids (each will have different project id). If you want one row per user id then you will have to use grouping functions like `group_concat`. Below is an example

```
SELECT u.id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name)
FROM users u JOIN fave_projects fp on u.id = fp.user_id
JOIN projects p ON fp.project_id = p.id
WHERE u.id = $userId
GROUP BY u.id;
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)'s the documentation of `group_concat`.

**Update**

If you want to see the projects only, then the below should do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name
FROM users u JOIN fave_projects fp on u.id = fp.user_id
JOIN projects p ON fp.project_id = p.id
WHERE u.id = $userId;
```

**Update**

To make the existing query work, you need to add `DISTINCT` to it, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fav_project.project_id, fav_project.user_id, project.id, project.name
FROM fav_project
JOIN users
JOIN project
ON fav_project.project_id = project.id
WHERE fav_project.user_id = $userId"
```

Comment: Itll only be shown to the user who is logged in. So it isnt like a list of users vs projects.

Comment: Hm no, its not outputting anything?

Comment: I get `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean`

Comment: Maybe the user you are trying the query for does not have any projects? Can you try running the query in MySQL console or post some example data?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I would go with excalty the same answer but with an OUTER join so he should get a results (from users) even if there no projects.

Comment: My query here: `SELECT fp.project_id, fp.user_id, p.id, p.name, u.id
        FROM users AS u
        JOIN fav_project AS fp
        JOIN project AS p
        ON fp.project_id = p.id
        WHERE fp.user_id = $userId` returns the correct projects associated to that user(s) but duplicated?

Comment: your missing the DISTINCT in the provided answer DISTINCT will give only unique results

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier I have added DISTINCT query as another answer, danjbh can you try again?

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier that does not seem to alter anything though with or witohut